# Computing the correlation of residuals to income

Tags: r, regression, correlation

So here's what I have so far,

```
 library(faraway)
 x <- lm(gamble ~ sex+status+income+verbal, data= teengamb)
```

Then I found the correlation between the fitted values and the residuals

```
 zapsmall(cor(fitted(x), resid(x)))
```

So now I need to find the correlation between the residuals and income
Do I need to create a matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not. You are comparing two variables, the matrix would therefore by 1 by 1 (ie a scalar)

`cor(teengamb$income, resid(x))`